# How to explain this figure about `nvidia-smi` with NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have just run the `simpleMultiGPU` in a server with two `K20m` GPUs installed. And then run the `nvidia-smi` command to show the status of the GPUs. The result is as follows:

[image]

The problems are as follows:

1. the GPU Memory Usage seems to be not the same.
2. the Volatile GPU-Util of `device 1` is 99%.

Any advice?

Comment: What does simpleMultiGPU print to the console? There might be a very good chance that it just doesn't spawn enough work for both GPUs.

Comment: Hi, thanks! The console output of `simpleMultiGPU` is blocked at `generating input data ...`, and I wait for five more or less minutes, it also stop at there, and during the time, I also use the `nvidia-smi` to check the status, there seems to be nothing changed from that. The I use `Ctrl+C` to stop the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no concept that says memory utilization must be the same when running apps on more than one GPU.  Furthermore, memory utilization can vary at different points in the application, depending on the underlying activity (such as the point at which allocations are made) when the sampling of memory usage occurs.
2. The Volatile GPU usage of device 1 probably indicates that the application and/or `nvidia-smi` is causing activity on device 1.

It's not clear why you refer to these as problems.  You are monitoring activity on the device.